# The augmentation ideal of $\mathbb{Z}G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, group-rings

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $p$ and let $IG$ denote the augmentation ideal of the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$. I need to find $H^1(G,IG)$.
Since 
$$0 \rightarrow IG \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$$
Then we get the long exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow H^0(G,IG) \rightarrow H^0(G,\mathbb{Z}G) \rightarrow H^0(G,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^1(G,IG) \rightarrow 0$$
as $\mathbb{Z}G$ is projective. 
I'm not sure how to get it using the above sequence. Is there an alternative way?

Thanks for help.